# HtDP2e Prologue create-rocket-scene.v6 error

Tags: racket

Given Figure 8: Landing a rocket (version 6) from http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/part_prologue.html:

```
(require 2htdp/image)

; properties of the “world”
(define WIDTH  100)
(define HEIGHT 100)

; properties of the descending rocket
(define A 1)

; various other constants 
(define MTSCN  (empty-scene WIDTH HEIGHT))
(define ROCKET .)
(define ROCKET-CENTER-TO-BOTTOM
  (- HEIGHT (/ (image-height ROCKET) 2)))

(define X 50)

; functions
(define (create-rocket-scene.v6 t)
  (cond
    [(<= (distance t) ROCKET-CENTER-TO-BOTTOM)
     (place-image ROCKET X (distance t) MTSCN)]
    [(> (distance t) ROCKET-CENTER-TO-BOTTOM)
     (place-image ROCKET X ROCKET-CENTER-TO-BOTTOM MTSCN)]))

(define (distance t)
  (* 1/2 A (sqr t)))
```

when I run:

```
(animate create-rocket-scene.v6)
```

as requested in the book:

> As always, you can run this program with animate:
>
> > (animate create-rocket-scene.v6)

Got following error:

create-rocket-scene.v6: expected a function call, but there is no open parenthesis before this function

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this line to your program (definition area):

```
(require 2htdp/universe)
```

to make `animate` available to your program.

[image: require animate line]